# If Ethernet is added to a bridge, mdns no longer works

Tags: macos, network, catalina

When I create a bridge with Ethernet, mdns no longer works.

Testing steps:

1. Verify mdns working(success):
   ping macmini.local (or any other server on the network support mdns)
2. System Preferences -> Network
3. Delete Ethernet, click Apply
4. Manage Virtual Interfaces -> + New Bridge
5. Check mark Ethernet, then click Create
6. Click Apply
7. Reboot (Must reboot or flush dns/mdns cache)
8. Verify mdns no longer working(fail):
   ping macmini.local (or any other server on the network support mdns)

Anyone experiencing this? Any solution?

PS: Above is easy to revert:

1. Delete bridge, click [Apply]
2. Add(+) Ethernet, click [Apply].
3. If dhcp is use no additional steps, else re-enter manual config and click [Apply].